# Need to understand the working of this java code

Tags: java

What I've understood so far is that it will read the file line by line and simultaneously, it will split the record and save it in fields array, after that I am not able to understand what it will add in records List .... as it is directly adding the fields array to list.

```
String fileName = "C:\\data.csv"

public static Collection<String[]> getTestData(fileName) throws IOException {
    List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String record;
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    while ((record=file.readLine())!=null) {
        String fields[] = record.split(",");
        records.add(fields);
    }
    file.close();
    return records;
}
```

CSV File

```
160,45,17.6,Underweight
168,70,24.8,Normal
181,89,27.2,Overweight
178,100,31.6,Obesity
```

Comment: what do you need to understand the java code for?  Do you have to change it?

Comment: Have you tried anything to understand the code? If so, please post your thoughts and we'll gladly correct you in order to help you learn.

Comment: This is a basic loop. Like others said, you need to give where you're having trouble. If I had to explain this to someone I would say: "It loops through the file, and splits each line by commas." That's obviously not what you're looking for, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: What I've understood so far is that it will read the file line by line and simultaneously, it will split the record and save it in fields array, after that I am not able to understand what it will add in records List .... as it is directly adding the fields array to list.. @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @user2747831 put that in the question.

Comment: @user2747831: then you understood most of it. If you wrote *that* in the question, you'd have avoided a few downvotes and we'd have known what part to answer. The way you posted it first looks like you have *no idea at all* and that would have required an *entirely different* (and far more elaborate) answer.

Comment: I just want to know what will be my first element in the list records?

I've added the csv file in the question.

Comment: @user2747831 your first element will be an array of the first line in the file, delimited by comma. Given the CSV file you posted, it should be ["160", "45", "17.6", "Underweight"]. That is the first thing in your list.

Comment: if its returning the same value as its there in the CSV, then why on the first place they have splitted it. It could save the csv in a list?

Answer (score 1):

1. Sets up a list of string arrays.
2. Reads each line from data.csv
3. For each line, split up into an array using commas as delimiters and add array to the list
4. Return the list.

**EDIT:**

What you end up with is a list of string arrays.

---

If your csv file looked like this:

abc,123

rtf,434

lmo,554

---

Then your list of string arrys would look like this:

list item 1: String[] {"abc", "123"}

list item 2: String[] {"rtf", "434"}

list item 3: String[] {"lmo", "554"}

Comment: +1 for beginners it will be difficult to understand at first. Good you supported him

Comment: if its returning the same value as its there in the CSV, then why on the first place they have splitted it. It could save the csv in a list?

Comment: They have probably split it up into arrays so that they could manipulate the data before looping back through and adding it into the file. They may even be mapping each array to an object.

Answer (score 1):

`records` is declared with the following:

```
List<String[]> records ...
```

That means that it's a List of an Array of strings.

Each item of the list will have the type `String[]`

---

`fields` is an array, so when the folloiwng line is executed

```
records.add(fields);
```

it's adding the `fields` array to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = "C:\\data.csv" //set the location of a comma seperated value file

public static Collection<String[]> getTestData(fileName) throws IOException {
    List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>(); // instantiate an array list object to hold the fields to be returned
    String record;
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); // open the file for reading
    while ((record=file.readLine())!=null) { //read the file line by line, execute the code in the curly brackets until an empty line or end of file is reached
        String fields[] = record.split(","); //split up each line into an array, each elemet will be delimited by a comma
        records.add(fields); // add each element to the array list object created earlier
    }
    file.close();
    return records; //return all the fields found in the file
}
```

So for example with a file containing:

```
one,two,three
red,green,gold
```

this method would return a string array list of:

```
{ "one","two","three" }
{ "red","green","gold" }
```

**Edit:**

In the case of the data you added this would return an array list of:

```
{ 160, 45, 17.6, Underweight }
{ 168, 70, 24.8, Normal }
{ 181, 89, 27.2, Overweight }
{ 178, 100, 31.6, Obesity }
```

Comment: This is incorrect. He would end up with a list containing two String arrays, one holding "one,two,three" and one holding "red,green,gold"

Comment: Yep, fixed typo as you were commenting :)

Answer (score 0):

The method uses a List.

This is much like an array of arrays, except the outer array is dynamic.

String#split returns an array of strings. We add that array to our list, and return the list of arrays at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = "C:\\data.csv"       // This is the file to be read

// Method is public: can be called from anywhere in the package and class
//           static so can be called without instance.
//           return type is Collection<String []> Collection Of String Array
//           takes filename as argument
//           throws IOException since we are reading from a file

public static Collection<String[]> getTestData(fileName) throws IOException {

    // record is the List which is a Collection of String Arrays we will return
    List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    String record;

    // Reading the File
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    // Read line by line unless the last line is null
    while ((record=file.readLine())!=null) {
        String fields[] = record.split(",");   // splits the line with delimiter ","
        records.add(fields);
    }
    file.close();   // Close the file
    return records; // return the Collection
}
```

[split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)